# Strength biceps-triceps

Tags: strength

How can be produced a powerful punch.What muscles needs? I workout biceps and triceps,does this play a role or is clearly about technique.What should I improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a number of years since I've studied any form of striking art, but from what I remember, it's mainly technique followed by a surprising amount of the core / trunk and lower body.

> For example, one study of 100+ amateur boxers (conducted by Filiminov) used tensiometric dynamometers to determine the origin and nature of punching power. Their findings concluded that almost 40% of the power from a punch is produced by the lower body. As much as 38 percent is associated with trunk rotation. Their research confirmed that the initiation of a punch starts at the ground (feet) and travels up the legs through the hips (multiplying in force).

Taken from [here](http://rosstraining.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=816745#p816745).

Comment: Imagine you want to throw a ball with more power so it can go farther. The power you want to generate will never come from the biceps/triceps. It will come from a combination of generative body swing into a rotational force, from hips, legs, core, altogether, timed correctly to deliver the ball at the right moment. In the old days, we used to have to break terra cotta roof tiles piles with our punches. This required a bit more strength building in the wrist and forearm or the bones & joints would break easily. Still the power always came from the body.. Techniques & executions matter more.

Answer (score 0):

Muscles contract when they do work.

If you contract your bicep you perform a pulling motion, for triceps it is a pushing. For a punch you will be pushing, so triceps.

However, chest/pectoral strength plays a important part in the pushing motion of a punch.